# Is there a way to minimize the number of calls to __new__ in numerical python code?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm working to speed up some numerical modeling code written in python. It relies on `numpy` arrays and on a matrix solving method from `scipy.linalg`. It's a finite differences PDE solver. After profiling and taking care of some slower bits, the largest chunk of time is being taken up by the `built-in method __new__`. Is the `__new__` method executed every time a number is declared? Is there any way to avoid it? Here is the main loop of the solver:

```
    #iterate over time steps
for j in range(1,N_t):

    #store some numbers
    jm1 = j - 1
    mm2 = m - 2
    mm1 = m - 1
    mp1 = m + 1
    pm1 = p - 1
    pm2 = p - 2

    #load the "b vector"
    vec[0] = v1*C[0,jm1] + v2*C[1,jm1]
    for i in r_vec_a:
        vec[i] = hlam_a*C[i-1,jm1] + v3*C[i,jm1] + hlam_a*C[i+1,jm1]
    vec[mm1] = -f1*C[mm2,jm1] + f5*C[mm1,jm1] - f3*C[m,jm1] - f4*C[mp1,jm1]
    vec[m] = -g1*C[mm2,jm1] - g2*C[mm1,jm1] + g5*C[m,jm1] - g4*C[mp1,jm1]
    for i in r_vec_b:
        vec[i] = hlam_b*C[i-1,jm1] + v4*C[i,jm1] + hlam_b*C[i+1,jm1]
    vec[pm1] = v5*C[pm2,jm1] + v6*C[pm1,jm1]

    #solve the matrix equation for new concentrations
    C[:,j] = scipy.linalg.solve_banded(u1, banded, vec, check_finite = u2,
        overwrite_b = u3)

    #compute boundary values (with 2 extra orders of accuracy because it's easy)
    C_x0[0,j] = w1*C[0,j] - w2*C[1,j] + w3*C[2,j] - w4*C[3,j]
    C_xL[0,j] = e1*C[mm2,j] + e2*C[mm1,j] + e3*C[m,j] + e4*C[mp1,j]
    C_yL[0,j] = K_r*C_xL[0,j]
    C_y0[0,j] = -w4*C[p-4,j] + w3*C[p-3,j] - w2*C[pm2,j] + w1*C[pm1,j]
```

My first though was to store all the indexing variables and constants if they get reused, but that didn't reduce the calls to `__new__`.

Comment: `__new__` is the constructor. i doubt you can avoid it without doing your own optimising by re-writing the C code.

Comment: That's what I figured. But I don't know why so many `__new__` constructions are taking place. Essentially all of the variables are set at the beginning of the script, then repeatedly reused. Also, the number of `__new__` calls is fewer than the number of calls to the matrix solver, so it can't be the solver. Does a simple assignment like `x = 4` call the `__new__` method for the integer?

Comment: `x = 4` probably won't because `4` will be cached by the interpreter.  More complex things like `x = my_numpy_array[4]` _will_ probably call `__new__` however.

Comment: How did you profile? You might get misleading results. You should show your code for optimization.

Comment: I'm using `cProfile.run` to profile the code.

Comment: "Essentially all of the variables are ... repeatedly reused" - you may be misinterpreting how variables work in Python. Reusing variables doesn't automatically reuse the memory of the objects assigned to those variables.

Comment: Don't focus on `__new__`.  `__new__` and `__init__` are used when Python creates an object, an instance of a class (esp. new-style).  `numpy` arrays are created with a custom `__new__` (but not a `__init__`).  Whether they show up in the profile or not, it's not something you have control over.  Even if called frequently it probably isn't taking up a lot time.

Comment: When I said i'm reusing variables, I meant that I'm setting all the constants that I need to variables, so that even small things like `1. + lam_b` are stored and reused. I didn't mean that I'm reusing variable names. I'm not even doing any fancy slicing, just regular old integer assignments like `C[0,j] = `. I can't see where 2000 new objects would be constructed.

Comment: "I'm not even doing any fancy slicing, just regular old integer assignments like `C[0,j] =`" - well there's your problem! You want to shove as much work as possible out of explicit Python loops and into NumPy whole-array operations, since the NumPy operations get to loop in C and avoid a whole ton of repetitive type checks and other interpreter overhead.

Comment: Hmm. I can't avoid singling out certain elements of arrays. Do those assignments trip the `__new__` constructors? I know I'm running up against the natural operation of the language, but even if it's not possible to speed it up more, it'd be nice to know why.

Comment: Abstract discussion like this isn't going to help.  I think we need to see some code.  I assume you have a function that returns a differential or jacobian array, and gets called repeatedly by the `linalg` solver.  We need to see that, or a simplification.

Comment: Alright, I posted the main loop of the solver. `C`, `vec`, `C_x0`, etc. are numpy arrays and the rest of the variables like `v1`, `f3`, and `e4` are scalar floats.

Comment: I believe you are dealing with a sort of XY problem. Instead of asking how to efficiently compute what you want you are forcing us to only look at your solution, with partial information about it. These kind of questions rarely get a good answer that actually optimally solves your problem. you should just post your code (entirely, so that we can run it and profile it by ourselves). In this way people can give better suggestions then just optimizing a few low-level operations.

Comment: Well, I'd likely also be criticized for pasting 300 lines of numerical code into a question and saying "make it faster, please." But I can't post the whole solution anyway, so it's moot. I'm going to check different sections of the initialization code to see if they're tripping all the `__new__` methods. Maybe it's caused by an `import`.

Answer (score 0):

Profiler should tell you which object's `__new__` method is being called.

One thing which stands out in your code is that there's quite a bit of copying behind the scenes in your `solve_banded` call.

The answer is in the source of `solve_banded`:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.1/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L180-L255

If your scipy version is 0.15.1 or below, it does not special case tridiagonal matrices and copies your input into a larger matrix for LAPACK (see the `not l==u==1` branch in the source).

Since you're doing things in the loop, you might want to call the relevant LAPACK functions directly: just inline the relevant parts of `solve_banded`. Then profile again.